# Delete text before the specific occurrence of a character in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
string1 = 'bla/bla1/blabla/bla2/bla/bla/wowblawow1'
```

I need to take the text after the last '/' and delete everything else:

```
string2 = 'wowblawow1'
```

Is there any method I could use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string1 = 'bla/bla1/blabla/bla2/bla/bla/wowblawow1'
string2 = string1.split(r'/')[-1] # Out[2]: 'wowblawow1'
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split to see how it works. But as @Emilien suggested, if are looking for extracting basename, use `os.path`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: I was looking for the basename, but it works both ways, thanks :)

Comment: then you might be interested in https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split and use `os.path.basename`, it handles all funny edge cases, like escaped slash in file name (e.g. `'/tmp/foo\/bar'`)

Answer (score 5):

Or maybe you are even looking for this?

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename("/var/log/syslog")
'syslog'
>>> os.path.dirname("/var/log/syslog")
'/var/log'
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally use `os.path.basename` when dealing with forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be the most practical way, but for generally trying to locate the content after the last occurrence of something:

```
string1 = 'bla/bla1/blabla/bla2/bla/bla/wowblawow1'
index = (len(string1)-1) - string1[::-1].find('/')
string1 = string1[index+1:]
```

deatils:

```
string1[::-1] # reverse the string
string1[::-1].find(my_string_to_search_for) # gets the index of the first occurance of the argument in the string.
(len(string1)-1) # the maximum index value
(len(string1)-1) - string[::-1].find(my_string_to_search_for) # the index as taken from the front of the string
string1 = string1[index+1:] # gives the substring of everything after the index of the last occurance of your string
```

You could make the code more readable by doing something like:

```
def get_last_index_of(string,search_content):
    return (len(string)-1) - string[::-1].find(search_content)

string1 = 'bla/bla1/blabla/bla2/bla/bla/wowblawow1'
string1 = string1[get_last_index_of('/')+1:]
```

Comment: if you really want to do this manually `string1[string1.rfind('/')+1:]` would be sufficient...

Comment: @m.wasowski now wheres the fun in that ;)

Comment: fun would be `string1[{ch: i for i,ch in enumerate(string1, start=1)}['/']:]`

Comment: @m.wasowski hahaha touche